# How can I use isPressed()

Tags: android, button

How can I use `isPressed();`?
I need to do something like this:

```
if (btn1.isPressed){
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: are you trying "do something" when your button is clicked?

Comment: You should use '()' in your code.  so: 
`if (btn1.isPressed()){
    //Do something
}`

Answer (score 1):

Use **OnTouch** listener:

```
btn1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                    // btn1 is pressed
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```